# Convert day of year (from extract) back to a date

Tags: postgresql, date

I am trying to group data by the day of the year that it falls on. I have been able to achieve this with the code below. The issue is that I lose the information as to which day (i.e. Jan 1st, Jan 2nd etc) each grouping represents. I am simply left with a number (e.g. 1, 2 etc.) representing the day of the year. Is there any to convert this number back into the more descriptive date?  Thanks a lot.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp2 AS
SELECT  extract(doy from trd_exctn_dt) as day_of_year
        ,sum(dollar_vol) AS dollar_vol
FROM tmp
GROUP BY extract(doy from trd_exctn_dt);
```

Current Output:

```
day_of_year | dollar_vol
------------|------------
    1            10
    2            15
    3             7
```

Desired Output: N.b. The exact format of the first column doesn't matter too much. I would be happy with DD/MM, MM/DD or any other clear output.

```
day_of_year | dollar_vol
------------|------------
 Jan 1      |      10
 Jan 2      |      15
 Jan 3      |       7
```

Comment: Use [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) fucntion:

```
SELECT  to_char(trd_exctn_dt,'MM/DD') as day_of_year ,sum(dollar_vol) AS dollar_vol
FROM tmp
GROUP BY day_of_year  ;
```